# How do I create an Android menu with two screens?

Tags: android, android-layout

My problem is my main menu has more than 40 items.  I'd like to show that in two screens like the home screen in Android.  How can i do that?  Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/andro-views/) example might give you some idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think use could use multiple tabs.
Sorry im jst a begginer so pardon me if this is wrong.

Comment: its ok.I know that but see the home screen on your emulator.it has three pages when you drag your mouse left.You will see music widget.I want to do that.If u get the soln please reply me.ok

Comment: There is no mouse in android.

Comment: Sudheesh, your idea and answer could be improved if you can show an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`ViewSwitcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) and switch the views using a gesturedetector